# How frequently Broadcast Receiver get wifi scan update?

Tags: java, android

**GOAL:** get wifi scan results periodically (I would be able to choose the period).

**PROBLEM:** I'm trying to get wifi scan results. I'm using this snippet of code.
From what I understood when I register the receiver using the `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` constant I'm saying: "when an access points scan result broadcast is available notify me".

I searched and I found `startScan()` to be the method I was looking for but unfortunately....

> **public boolean startScan ()**
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 28.
>   The ability for apps to trigger scan requests will be removed in a future release.

**QUESTION:** is there a method which substitute `startScan()` or another way to trigger the scan when I need it?
How can I know the frequency of wifi scan updates?

```
 wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Check if wifi is enabled. Enables it otherwise.
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WiFi is disabled. Let's enable it.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // CHANGE_WIFI_STATE permission allow this
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                localMaxSignalStrength = 1;
                results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

                    ScanResult el = results.get(i);
                    int signalLevel = wifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(el.level, 5);

                    if (signalLevel > localMaxSignalStrength){
                        localMaxSignalStrength = signalLevel;
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SSID:" + el.SSID + "frequency" + el.frequency + "lev:" + signalLevel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                unregisterReceiver(this);

            }
        };

        registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

**EDIT 1**

Reading better the documentation on Broadcast Receiver I found that if you don't call unregister receiver you keep receiving broadcast messages you registered for.

> To stop receiving broadcasts, call
>   unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver). Be sure to
>   unregister the receiver when you no longer need it or the context is
>   no longer valid.

I've tried to uncomment `unregisterReceiver(this);` and seems that now I continuosly receive Wifi scan results.

**EDIT 2 (09/2018)**

What I wrote above, particularly the fact that I was **continuously** receiving scan results was true for *Android 4.2.2 (JellyBean)*. Since I've moved my testing on an *Android 7.0 (Nougat)* , I've noticed that (without unregister the receiver) I wasn't receiving wifi scan results in a continuous manner as with the previous OS version but very slow (minutes between the scans).

In this case I was forced to use `WifiManager` 's `startScan()` method (note: deprecated on API 28). Anyway this method has some restrictions as reported below.

> The following limitations apply to the frequency of scans using
>   WifiManager.startScan().
>
> Android 8.0 and Android 8.1:
>
> Each background app can scan one time in a 30-minute period.
>
> Android 9 and later:
>
> Each foreground app can scan four times in a 2-minute period. This
>   allows for a burst of scans in a short time.
>
> All background apps combined can scan one time in a 30-minute period.

Comment: So what is the best way to start the scan in android Pie???